# Kronecker product of diagonal matrices

Tags: tensor-calculus, linear-algebra, quantum-computer, matrix-elements

I'm trying to figure out how one would come up with a case for [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of diagonal matrices. Suppose we have a $2\times 2$ matrices
$$M_i = \begin{bmatrix}
a_i && 0\\
0 && b_i
\end{bmatrix}.$$
I want to figure out
$$M = \bigotimes_{i=1}^n M_i.$$
What would the diagonal elements of matrix $M$ would be?

Comment: They're enumerated in a way similar to the way binary counts up - if you write out the case $n=3$, you may be able to see the pattern

Comment: Yeah, i wrote down up to 4 and saw some patterns but I got stuck generalising it

Comment: Math questions with no physics context should be posted on Math SE.